# Parser Error Message '(Default)' is not a valid value for attribute 'culture'

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: '(Default)' is not a valid value for attribute 'culture'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="FundingWebsiteAspnet.HomePage" Line 2: MasterPageFile="MasterPageForTheFundingWebsite.master" Culture="(Default)" %> Line 3:
>
> Source File: /HomePage.aspx Line: 1
>
> Also this error messageWarning 1 C:\Users\shussain2\Documents\CTRP\FundingWebsiteAspnet\FundingWebsiteAspnet\HomePage.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.1.220.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) C:\Users\shussain2\Documents\CTRP\FundingWebsiteAspnet\FundingWebsiteAspnet\HomePage.aspx 1 1 CTRP

What can I do to fix this problem? I had the idea to downgrade but i want the new controls to be compatable with it.

Code HOMEPAGE.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="FundingWebsiteAspnet.HomePage"
    MasterPageFile="MasterPageForTheFundingWebsite.master" 
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="mainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheetForTheFundingWebsite.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .modalBackground
            {
                background-color: Gray;
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: 0.7;
                border: 5px
                border-color: Black;
                border-style: solid;
            }
            .pnlBackGround
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 10%;
                left: 10px;
                width: 650px;
                height: 300px;
                background-color: White;
                border: solid 3px black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="TKSM" EnablePageMethods="true" EnableCdn="true" ScriptMode="Release"
        runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="False"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="Study_Number" Width="100%" SkinID="Summary" OnRowCommand="grd_ReturnItems_RowCommand"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="236px"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField EditText="Vaishali" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PI" HeaderText="PI" SortExpression="PI" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Study_Number" HeaderText="Study_Number" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="Study_Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Study_Title" HeaderText="Study_Title" SortExpression="Study_Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Disease_Code" HeaderText="Disease_Code" SortExpression="Disease_Code" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:adm_productionConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PI], [Study Number] AS Study_Number, [Study Title] AS Study_Title, [Disease Code] AS Disease_Code FROM [Study_Disease_Code_association]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe_EditReturnItemPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btn_Hidden1"
        PopupControlID="EditReturnItemDialog" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="btn_EditReturnItemCancel"
        DropShadow="false" PopupDragHandleControlID="EditReturnItemDialogHeader" OkControlID="btnOk"
        X="20" Y="100" />
    <asp:Panel ID="EditReturnItemDialog" runat="server" Style="display: none; width: 300px"
        CssClass="pnlBackGround">

        <br />
        Please Enter Disease Code :
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    Select Disease Code Type:
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="radDropDownDiseaseType" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    Select sub-category :
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="radDropDownSubCat" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>

                    Enter Meddra Code :
                   <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="radDropDownMeddra" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>

                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>

           <asp:Button ID="btn_SaveEditReturnItem" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_SaveEditReturnItem_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="btn_EditReturnItemCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           </td>
           </tr>
                      <tr>
           <td>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <center>
            </center>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Hidden1" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Culture="(Default)"` from aspx page.

Remove `<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" .... %>` from aspx page.

Place telerik namespace inside your web.config.

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages>
      <controls>
        ...
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" 
           assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
        ...
      </controls>
    </pages>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: I did accordingly and I still get this message    
Parser Error 
 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="FundingWebsiteAspnet.HomePage"
Line 2:      MasterPageFile="MasterPageForTheFundingWebsite.master" %>
Line 3:   

Source File: /HomePage.aspx    Line: 1 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.1.220.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' could not be loaded.

Comment: Please post `HomePage.aspx` code, and exception (if it is different). By the way, are you using telerik controls?

Comment: yes I am, I just upgraded the controls. The site was fully functional but it broke after the upgrade. Also, I have posted the error message below and the code above.

Comment: Warning 1 C:\Users\shussain2\Documents\CTRP\FundingWebsiteAspnet\FundingWebsiteAspnet\HomePage.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls. C:\Users\shussain2\Documents\CTRP\FundingWebsiteAspnet\FundingWebsiteAspnet\HomePage.aspx 1 1 CTRP

Comment: Move `<head>` and `<form>` tags to Mater page.

Comment: Do you know how to downgrade telerik?

Comment: Could you replace RadDropDownList with regular asp.net DropDownList, and test it again? If still throw error, please post the exception.